# How to install VHDL syntax highlighting for Sublime Text 2?

Tags: sublimetext2, vhdl

I am trying to install this [VHDL highlighting package](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/VHDL) for my Sublime Text 2.

I already installed the elusive Package Control following the instructions [here](https://packagecontrol.io/installation).

But when I search for the package within Ctrl + Shift + P, the package doesn't show up!

[image: Could not find package.]

What do I do? According to the plugin's page, it should work for Sublime Text 2.

Comment: May I ask why the downvote? So I can improve my questions in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plugin's description is out of date. If you look again at the plugin's Package Control page, you'll see an `ST3` icon at the top, just to the right of the author's name. So, you'll need to [upgrade to ST3](http://sublimetext.com/3) to use it, and I strongly suggest upgrading anyway. Even though ST3 is still labeled as a "beta", it's rock-solid and a great improvement over ST2 in a number of ways, not the least of which is an improved API that allows for all these great ST3-specific plugins. I've been using it exclusively for well over two years now without major issues.

Comment: Thank you very much, the "beta" label made me stick with ST2 but you've encouraged me to definitely upgrade. Will do it now, thanks.